# Laravel connection between controller, views and routes

Tags: php, laravel

i'm new to laravel and i'm trying to figure out how to link views and urls.. i have this HomeController.php:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    public function index(){

        $this->layout->title = 'Web Title';
        $this->layout->content = View::make('home');

    }

}
```

it has a layouts.master (views/layouts/master.blade.php) with this content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('css/styles.css')}}" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">

        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            asdasd
        </div>
        <div class="mainContent">
            @yield('content')
        </div><!--mainContent End-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is home.blade.php inside root "views" folder

```
@section('content')
    <div class="userSearchInfo">
        <div class="userPhoto"></div>
        <div class="userData">
            <div class="userName">
                Name
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

and finally routes.php, i think here's the problem, i don't understand if it's ok or not, it varies from website to website, i don't really know what i should use, laravel api is not good at all, no information about this

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

Hope you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `routes.php` file you declare the `URL`s you application responds to, for example, you have following route declaration in your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

It tells the framework that, whenever a request to landing page is made, the `index` method of `HomeController` controller should be invoked.

So, a route is used to register a `URL` in your application and on the request of that `URL` the action registered with that route will be taken. In your example, `/` is the `URL` for landing/home page and action you have registered for that `URL` is `'HomeController@index'`, it means `index` method will be executed from the `HomeController`.

Enable, debug mode by setting `debug => true` from `app/config/app.php` file so you can track the errors because after enabling the `debug` mode, you'll get informative error details. Also, `Laravel` is the best place to learn the basic about the framework, so read the documentation properly.

Comment: weird, on my localhost/laravel/public it says: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Comment: wow thx for debug info :D the problem was: $this->layout->title = 'Web Title';
error was: Use of undefined constant title - assumed 'title'